# Case sensitive uniqueness failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have an issue with uniqueness validation using Ruby on Rails Tutorial "Learn Web Development with Rails" Third Edition by Michael Hartl.

I was supposed to add uniqueness validation for emails for new user.

This is my user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,presence: true, length:{maximum: 50}
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX=/\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i 
  validates :email,presence:true, length:{maximum: 255}, format:{with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive:false}
end
```

I keep getting errors in the command terminal:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException
```

Did anybody have the same issue with case sensitive uniqueness?

Comment: Looks like there are no issue actually. You are adding the same `email` again.

Comment: I am unsure what email I am adding again. I haven't gotten to the part were they build the form. I don't have anything in my db. All I have been using is sandbox just to simulate what would happen

Comment: The text book just says at that point you are suppose to get green meaning everything is okay. But instead the terminal just gives me red errors when I run bundle exec rake test:models.

Comment: Oh one thing I noticed that doing validates: true works fine, but once I add validates:{ case_sensitive:false} it just falls apart.

Comment: okay I have figured out the problem. It was related to my database all I had to run was bundle exec rake db:reset, and I was under way. Thank you